# Anime/Manga where the main character goes to a magical town and completes missions

Tags: story-identification, manga

To the best of my recollection, the main character lives with a woman in a small house, possibly atop a hill. I don't think they were blood related but the woman had some connections to a magic association.

There is an attempted robbery by some bandits that are passing by, trying to make some fast money. The main character gets involved and I think they beat the bandits but then some people from the magic association turn up in zeppelins(?) and for a reason they take him with them.

The protagonist is sad to leave but agrees and they end up in a (hidden?) magic town where if you want to stay, you have to complete missions to extend your time. He gets lessons on how to use magic from an old ugly lady.

Answer (score -1):

That kinda sounds like the anime Radiant (https://myanimelist.net/anime/37202/Radiant) tbh but not entirely sure if that’s what you’re looking for

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Please add details to your answer to explain the points that match the question and what doesn't fit.